# Removing trailing whitespace in Zsh: fatal error: out of heap memory

Tags: regex, unix, text, ascii, zsh

Anybody know why I'm getting this and how to prevent it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

setopt nullglob
setopt extendedglob

for file in **/*; do
  if file -b $file | grep -q "text"; then
    raw=$(<$file)

    # Remove trailing whitespace
    raw=${raw//[[:blank:]]##$'\n'/$'\n'}

    # Other stuff like removing CR+LF works fine
    # raw=${raw//$'\r'}

    echo $file
    printf "%s\n\n" $raw > $file
  fi
done
```

Comment: **off-topic:** Do the lines end with `##`? Also, `$(...)` strips the ending newline(s), so you might "miss" some blanks in the last line of the file.

Comment: Does using `${raw//$'[ \t]##\n'/$'\n'}` gives the same error?

Answer (score 1):

Fravadona fixed it with `${raw//$'[ \t]##\n'/$'\n'}`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know why this solution works; I just made the assumption that `[[:blank:]]` might be broken because `${raw//$'\r'/}` was working fine